# Unable to take backup of mysql database using Xtrabackup

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, backup, xtrabackup

I am trying to take mysql backup without any downtime but unable to take the backup using Xtrabackup .

Actual Database is almost about 40+ GB in size. I am trying to first satisfy myself. Hence, I have created a sample database on a server with 5000 Tables (all InnoDB tables).
As per the blog "[there are some cases when you can get table entirely missing from the backup if you use this technique](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/23/best-kept-mysqldump-secret/) "  "--single-transaction  are not safe to use on production environment.

```
[root@localhost mysql]# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 56
Server version: 5.5.25a-log MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| innodbtest         |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> use innodbtest;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
Database changed
mysql> show create table T4000;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| T4000 | CREATE TABLE `T4000` (
  `A` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `B` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`A`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table T3040;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| T3040 | CREATE TABLE `T3040` (
  `A` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `B` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`A`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I used tool [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) and [**followed the steps to create a backup**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/creating_a_backup_ibk.html)

```
xtrabackup --backup --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --target-dir=/opt/bkp/
```

After taking the backup I am not getting the ".ibd" files at the backup location.

```
[root@localhost mysql]# ls -al /opt/bkp/
total 190676
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Nov 27 19:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root      4096 Nov 27 18:08 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root root 195035136 Nov 27 19:02 ibdata1
-rw-r----- 1 root root        79 Nov 27 19:02 xtrabackup_checkpoints
-rw-r----- 1 root root      2560 Nov 27 19:02 xtrabackup_logfile
[root@localhost mysql]#
```

After restoring the database using xtrabackup, I am not getting the database folder "innodbtest" on the other server too.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_flile_per_table';` and tell me is it is `ON` or `OFF`.

Comment: Please run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';` and tell me what it is.

Comment: Another question: Did you run `xtrabackup --prepare` ( http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/xtrabackup_bin/preparing_the_backup.html ) on the backup after running `xtrabackup --backup` ?

Comment: Here is the output                                                   mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_flile_per_table';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| datadir       | /var/lib/mysql/ |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
Yes I did run xtrabackup --prepare

Comment: Here is few more details  
mysql> show variables like "%innodb";
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| have_innodb           | YES   |
| ignore_builtin_innodb | OFF   |
+-----------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show variables like "%engine";
+------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| default_storage_engine | InnoDB |
| storage_engine         | InnoDB |
+------------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit below mansion urls and hope these references will help you.

http://johanandersson.blogspot.in/2012/10/hotbackup-of-galera-cluster-for-mysql.html

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/howtos/setting_up_replication.html